# Java compressing a .txt file

Tags: java, string, char, compression, bit

I am currently trying to write a program which reads in a compressed file which is written in bits or 0s and 1s, and convert them in to strings of 0s and 1s.

The School provided a class and method for reading 1 bit and converting that in to a character char. So to read and convert one bit to a char, all i need to do is type in my code:

```
char oneBit = inputFile.readBit();
```

in my main method.

How do I get my program to read over every bit within the compressed file and convert them to char? using the `.readBit` method? And how would I convert all the char 0s and 1s in to strings of 0s and 1s?

The readBit method:

```
public char readBit() {
    char c = 0;

    if (bitsRead == 8)
        try {
            if (in.available() > 0) { // We have not reached the end of the
                                        // file
                buffer = (char) in.read();
                bitsRead = 0;
            } else
                return 0;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from file ");
            System.exit(0); // Terminate the program
        }

    // return next bit from the buffer; bit is converted first to char
    if ((buffer & 128) == 0)
        c = '0';
    else
        c = '1';
    buffer = (char) (buffer << 1);
    ++bitsRead;

    return c;
}
```

where `in` is the input file.

Comment: Without a better understanding of the API you're using, we're not going to be able to help you. The API should provide you information about the number of bits it has available or an exist condition telling you when you've reached the end of the file (like returning `-1` for example)

Comment: I'm pretty new to java coding (started 1 week ago), so i'm a complete noob when it comes to coding terms. Could you explain what you meant please?
for this task we are not asked to do anything complicated, we were just asked to do this using while loops, for loops and concatenation of strings. :/

Comment: From a practical standpoint, all loops have an exit condition.  In your case, you are looping because you are only allowed to read one bit at a time, and presumably the input file contains many bits.  Do you know how many bits are in the files you are processing?

Comment: I've included the readBit method in the main question now. I think the exit condition is the in.available() > 0 right?
as for the number of bits, we have several different files for processing, and we can't really open these files  :/ they are compressed, so when opening these files in, it's all just symbols.

Comment: Remove the `available()` test. It is not a test for end of file. See the Javadoc. Just test the result of `in.read()` for -1 before you cast it to `char`.

Comment: Posting that code helped. Notwithstanding the available() issue, the readBit() method will return 0 when the file has been processed.  Otherwise, you get a '0' character or a '1' character.  Try creating a loop until the character read is zero (not to be confused with '0').

Comment: okay thank you! Would the condition for the loop be something like: 
char nextBit = 0;
 while ((nextBit = inputFile.readBit()) != 0){
        other stuff
}
so 0 with out the ' ' ?

Comment: Perfect... now you are getting somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it!  ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [resource](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/17au/homework/ass8/BitInputStream.java)

Sample implementation.

```
public class BitAnswer {

    final static int RADIX = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitInputStream bis = new BitInputStream("<file_name>");
        int result = bis.readBit();
        while( result != -1 ) {
            System.out.print(Character.forDigit(result, RADIX));
            result = bis.readBit();
        }

        System.out.println("\nAll bits read!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public  void compress(){
        String inputFileName = "c://tmp//content.txt";
        String outputFileName = "c://tmp//compressedContent.txt";
        FileOutputStream fos = null; 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream= null;    
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(inputFileName)))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            outputStream = new  DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream); // GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream) - use if you want unix .gz format
            outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
            String compressedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            fos=new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
            fos.write(compressedText.getBytes());
            System.out.println("done compress");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                if (byteArrayOutputStream != null) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                }
                if(fos != null){
                    fos.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("closed streams !!! ");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: This can compress 90% of original text.

Comment: It looks like the code in the answer is an inefficient way to encode text to base64. It doesn't compress the text, does it?